# matplotlib imshow(aspect='auto') produces rows of non-uniform height

Tags: python, matplotlib

The basic imshow plot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

aaa = np.arange(800).reshape((80, 10)) % 6

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 10))
img = ax.imshow(aaa, aspect='auto')

plt.show()
```

produces the following image:

[image]

Under very close inspection, the second row is clearly thicker than the first and the third row. I have tried to save the image as (.png) counting pixels, and as (.pdf) inspecting it in browser. In both cases I must conclude that the rows indeed have non-uniform height. Why? How can this be fixed? This is a minimum example of a figure I actually intend to publish, and there the effect looks even worse. I was hoping that aspect='auto' applies uniform stretch to the entire image...

Comment: This is an aliasing problem. If you save as `.png` you could set `dpi=600` or maybe higher. [savefig docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html)

Comment: @JohanC Thanks, that makes sense. But what about `.pdf`? There it is saved as a vector, right? Why is is uneven there?

Comment: An image is still saved as a raster in pdf.  If you want to control the resolution of that raster, use `fig.savefig('boo.pdf', dpi=300)` and the raster will be 300 dpi (even if the rest of the figure is vectors).  If you want the actual squares to be perfect vector graphics, then use `pcolormesh`.